# User with same Mail but a different additional info(like domain)

Tags: users, user-registration, email, wp-user-query

I know this is not the way u should go, but my customers want it so im looking for ways.
Requirement:

1. WP with one DB (3 Domains sale the same stuff)
2. 3 Domains which use this DB  (can be more later), this should work with on fly rewriting over hooks
3. user registered should be only able to login in the domain where he is registered, but should be able to register on the other 2 domains with same data.

My ideas:
Add the Domain as user meta
Problems:
E-Mail can be use only once on WordPress
I can't check the domain, for example in own code I would do the following which seems is not work on WordPress because wp use a Select statement which take a email lookup with a limit 1.

```sql
SELECT * from users WHERE email = “myemail” and password = PASSWORD(“mypw”) and domain = “thedomain where user is”.
```

Maybe Solutions:
Add the domain to the email on fly so user use name@gmx.de and in the db I will add domain1_name@gmx.de, but this brings new problems.

In the theory, i should do modification on the login query but this seems not so a good idea.

This Question is a little about WooCommerce but the main functions i need comes from Wordpress so i think this is the better place here.

Thanks

Comment: For the most part this sounds like core Multisite functionality. If you need to use custom SQL to select users for some reason, the `LIKE` operator is capable of matching the domain portion. That said, questions regarding third-party products such as WC are off-topic here, and if the question is not regarding Woo, then it's not really clear what the succinct question is, or what the current state/setup of the current site(s) is.

Comment: its about the core functionality of wp which use getuserbyId ans also getuserbyEmail (this is often use in jetpack) . Anyway i have talked with my customer and it seems like its okay for him when the user can register only one time so my problem is solved. On this point it would be interesting if i can hook the getUser function and mod so the byId functionality.